# Compress the build output into zip file with SVN revision in filename in Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins

I have a requirement to build my Visual Studio project on Jenkins. Then take the output and compress it into a zip file that has an SVN revision number in its name.

I tried to use Compress Artifacts Plugin, but there are several problems with it:

- The resulting archive includes the folder structure (i.e. if "Files to archive" is set to Proj/bin/Release/, the resulting archive will contain this path; I want just the content of Release directory)
- There seems to be no way to rename the zip file.
- If there were a way, I'm not sure, how to get the SVN revision number.

I've searched for other plugins, but there doesn't seem to be one to address my particular need (will be grateful for recomendations).

I've also considered using the batch command to compress the files and name it accordingly (still the problem of getting the revision number), than have compressed file as an artifact. As Windows doesn't have a built in command to zip files, i'd have to install stuff on build servers, which I'd rather not.

So, is there some built-in way to acomplish this or am I left with writing my own plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I have used PowerShell with Jenkins to handle tasks like this.

You mentioned that you don't want to install extra stuff, but I am not sure how to get around creating zips if the functionality is not there.

Since Windows does not have zipping utilities, you will probably have to install something like Community PowerShell Extensions or 7-Zip as that has a command line.

PowerShell might have some svn utilities or extensions also for grabbing the revision number from the svn repo.